# Updating tuple elements of a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

A program I am writing in Haskell has a list instance of my defined type:

```
type Locals = [(String, Float)]
```

I am trying to update this list by receiving a String and updating the corresponding float value, but the String might not be in the list at the time.

Since Haskell lists are immutable, I decided the easiest way was to do this (in pseudocode):

```
if a tuple containing the string exists:
    delete it

add the correct data
```

I want to know:

a) If there is an easier way to do this

b) If not, how would I go about deleting the correct element

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like an associative map.  I would use `Data.Map`.  This is known as a "dictionary" in other languages.   `Map.insert` does what you need.

Comment: It is not always a good idea to use a `Data.Map` in place of an association list. `Data.Map` is only faster for a large data structure, and often the association list is simpler to use and results in cleaner code. Here we have no information about how the association list is being used or what the data looks like, so it is hard to say.

Comment: @Yitz, I guess I challenge your claim about association lists being simpler and cleaner "often".  I have never experienced that.

Comment: That must be because you reach for `Data.Map` too often. :)

Comment: `Data.List.lookup` + `update (key, value) list = (key, value) : list` is **easy**.  Not scalable, but easy.

Comment: @Yitz, or maybe you don't reach for `Data.Map` too often enough!  :-P

Answer (score 3):

Seems that the best way to this would be to do

```
filter (\x -> fst x /= s) xs
```

Don't need any more help, thanks anyway.

Comment: That would remove _all_ entries of `x` (which might be exactly what you want).  If you want to only delete one (or know there is only one match) then just use Data.List.deleteBy:  `deleteBy ((== s) . fst) xs`.  If you use this, I'm guessing you'd have a use for other functions in Data.List, such as [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:lookup) and maybe [`insert`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:insert).

Answer (score 1):

`addToAL` from [`Data.List.Utils`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MissingH/0.18.6/doc/html/Data-List-Utils.html#3) does what you want.

> Adds the specified (key, value) pair to the given list, removing any existing pair with the same key already present.

Answer (score 0):

I am newbie for Haskell. Just for fun.

```
func xs str value = (str, value) : foldr step [] xs where
        step x acc
            | fst x == str = acc
            | otherwise = x:acc
```